# C# run a .bat file where some of the commands are to be run in an attached linux shell

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

I am able to execute a .bat file with these commands contained:

```
ssh -i BatchStagingVM_key.pem azureuser@xx.xxx.xx.xx  //works
timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK
echo blah
```

Essentially the first one runs, connecting to the VM, but the last two does not even register or get to the shell in the logged into linux vm command line. there is a few questions relating to executing .bat files, but none where some of the commands are to be executed on a vm on that same command line instance. Running these one at a time, works fine, but I want to automate this. Any advice/ideas/packages to check out?

[The linux VM command line, that isn't receiving commands from the .bat file execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyUAD.png)

Comment: Perhaps you simply need to precede `ssh` with the `start` command.